# how to differentiate Code vs Data bytes pefile

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, disassembly, opcode

Basically, I am trying to understand how to differentiate a bunch of bytes whether they are code or data?

Say I have the following bytes which are dissassembled:

```
b'.data\x00\x00\x00'
b"\xb9\x08\x00\x00\x00\xff\xd0\xb8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xe9L\xff\xff\xff\x0f\x1f\x80\x00\x00\x00\x001\xd2\xb9\x0b\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xf4\x06\x00\x00H\x83\xf8\x01tOH\x85\xc0t\x88\xb9\x0b
\x00\x00\x00\xff\xd0\xb8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xe9\x1d\xff\xff\xff\xba\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x04\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xc9\x06\x00\x00\x83\xc8\xff\xe9\x06\xff\xff\xfff\x0f\x1f\x84\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\xba\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x08\x00\x00\x00\xe8\xa9\x06\x00\x00\xb8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xe9\xe4\xfe\xff\xff\xba\x01\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x0b\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x90\x06\x00\x00\x83\xc8\
xff\xe9\xcd\xfe\xff\xffATWVSH\x83\xec(H\x8d\r`T\x00\x00\xff\x15.]\x00\x00H\x8b\x1d3T\x00\x00H\x85\xdbt2H\x8b=\xab]\x00\x00H\x8b54]\x00\x00\x8b\x0b\xff\xd7I\x89\xc4\xff\xd6\x85\x
c0u\x0eM\x85\xe4t\tH\x8bC\x08L\x89\xe1\xff\xd0H\x8b[\x10H\x85\xdbu\xdcH\x8d\r\x15T\x00\x00H\x83\xc4([^_A\\H\xff%!]\x00\x00\x0f\x1fD\x00\x00WVSH\x83\xec \x8b\x05\xdbS\x00\x00\x89
\xcfH\x89\xd6\x85\xc0u\nH\x83\xc4 [^_\xc3f\x90\xba\x18\x00\x00\x00\xb9\x01\x00\x00\x00\xe8!\x06\x00\x00H\x89\xc3H\x85\xc0t    <\x898H\x8d\r\xc0S\x00\x00H\x89p\x08\xff\x15\x8a\\\x00\
x00H\x8b\x05\x8fS\x00\x00H\x8d\r\xa8S\x00\x00H\x89\x1d\x81S\x00\x00H\x89C\x10\xff\x15\xb3\\\x00\x001\xc0H\x83\xc4 [^_\xc3\x83\xc8\xff\xeb\x9e\x0f\x1f\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00SH\x
83\xec \x8b\x05]S\x00\x00\x89\xcb\x85\xc0u\x0f1\xc0H\x83\xc4 [\xc3\x0f\x1f\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00H\x8d\rYS\x00\x00\xff\x15'\\\x00\x00H\x8b\r,S\x00\x00H\x85\xc9t*1\xd2\xeb\x0e\x0f\x
1f\x00H\x89\xcaH\x85\xc0t\x1bH\x89\xc1\x8b\x019\xd8H\x8bA\x10u\xebH\x85\xd2t&H\x89B\x10\xe8U\x05\x00\x00H\x8d\r\x16S\x00\x00\xff\x15,\\\x00\x001\xc0H\x83\xc4 [\xc3\x0f\x1f\x84\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
<CsInsn 0x200 [b908000000]: mov ecx, 8>
<CsInsn 0x205 [ffd0]: call rax>
<CsInsn 0x207 [b8ffffffff]: mov eax, 0xffffffff>
<CsInsn 0x20c [e94cffffff]: jmp 0x15d>
<CsInsn 0x211 [0f1f8000000000]: nop dword ptr [rax]>
<CsInsn 0x218 [31d2]: xor edx, edx>
<CsInsn 0x21a [b90b000000]: mov ecx, 0xb>
<CsInsn 0x21f [e8f4060000]: call 0x918>
<CsInsn 0x224 [4883f801]: cmp rax, 1>
<CsInsn 0x228 [744f]: je 0x279>
<CsInsn 0x22a [4885c0]: test rax, rax>
<CsInsn 0x22d [7488]: je 0x1b7>
<CsInsn 0x22f [b90b000000]: mov ecx, 0xb>
<CsInsn 0x234 [ffd0]: call rax>
<CsInsn 0x236 [b8ffffffff]: mov eax, 0xffffffff>
<CsInsn 0x23b [e91dffffff]: jmp 0x15d>
<CsInsn 0x240 [ba01000000]: mov edx, 1>
<CsInsn 0x245 [b904000000]: mov ecx, 4>
<CsInsn 0x24a [e8c9060000]: call 0x918>
<CsInsn 0x24f [83c8ff]: or eax, 0xffffffff>
<CsInsn 0x252 [e906ffffff]: jmp 0x15d>
<CsInsn 0x257 [660f1f840000000000]: nop word ptr [rax + rax]>
<CsInsn 0x260 [ba01000000]: mov edx, 1>
<CsInsn 0x265 [b908000000]: mov ecx, 8>
<CsInsn 0x26a [e8a9060000]: call 0x918>
<CsInsn 0x26f [b8ffffffff]: mov eax, 0xffffffff>
<CsInsn 0x274 [e9e4feffff]: jmp 0x15d>
<CsInsn 0x279 [ba01000000]: mov edx, 1>
<CsInsn 0x27e [b90b000000]: mov ecx, 0xb>
<CsInsn 0x283 [e890060000]: call 0x918>
<CsInsn 0x288 [83c8ff]: or eax, 0xffffffff>
<CsInsn 0x28b [e9cdfeffff]: jmp 0x15d>
<CsInsn 0x290 [4154]: push r12>
<CsInsn 0x292 [57]: push rdi>
<CsInsn 0x293 [56]: push rsi>
<CsInsn 0x294 [53]: push rbx>
<CsInsn 0x295 [4883ec28]: sub rsp, 0x28>
<CsInsn 0x299 [488d0d60540000]: lea rcx, [rip + 0x5460]>
<CsInsn 0x2a0 [ff152e5d0000]: call qword ptr [rip + 0x5d2e]>
<CsInsn 0x2a6 [488b1d33540000]: mov rbx, qword ptr [rip + 0x5433]>
<CsInsn 0x2ad [4885db]: test rbx, rbx>
<CsInsn 0x2b0 [7432]: je 0x2e4>
<CsInsn 0x2b2 [488b3dab5d0000]: mov rdi, qword ptr [rip + 0x5dab]>
<CsInsn 0x2b9 [488b35345d0000]: mov rsi, qword ptr [rip + 0x5d34]>
<CsInsn 0x2c0 [8b0b]: mov ecx, dword ptr [rbx]>
<CsInsn 0x2c2 [ffd7]: call rdi>
<CsInsn 0x2c4 [4989c4]: mov r12, rax>
<CsInsn 0x2c7 [ffd6]: call rsi>
<CsInsn 0x2c9 [85c0]: test eax, eax>
<CsInsn 0x2cb [750e]: jne 0x2db>
<CsInsn 0x2cd [4d85e4]: test r12, r12>
<CsInsn 0x2d0 [7409]: je 0x2db>
<CsInsn 0x2d2 [488b4308]: mov rax, qword ptr [rbx + 8]>
<CsInsn 0x2d6 [4c89e1]: mov rcx, r12>
<CsInsn 0x2d9 [ffd0]: call rax>
<CsInsn 0x2db [488b5b10]: mov rbx, qword ptr [rbx + 0x10]>
<CsInsn 0x2df [4885db]: test rbx, rbx>
<CsInsn 0x2e2 [75dc]: jne 0x2c0>
<CsInsn 0x2e4 [488d0d15540000]: lea rcx, [rip + 0x5415]>
<CsInsn 0x2eb [4883c428]: add rsp, 0x28>
<CsInsn 0x2ef [5b]: pop rbx>
<CsInsn 0x2f0 [5e]: pop rsi>
<CsInsn 0x2f1 [5f]: pop rdi>
<CsInsn 0x2f2 [415c]: pop r12>
<CsInsn 0x2f4 [48ff25215d0000]: jmp qword ptr [rip + 0x5d21]>
<CsInsn 0x2fb [0f1f440000]: nop dword ptr [rax + rax]>
<CsInsn 0x300 [57]: push rdi>
<CsInsn 0x301 [56]: push rsi>
<CsInsn 0x302 [53]: push rbx>
<CsInsn 0x303 [4883ec20]: sub rsp, 0x20>
<CsInsn 0x307 [8b05db530000]: mov eax, dword ptr [rip + 0x53db]>
<CsInsn 0x30d [89cf]: mov edi, ecx>
<CsInsn 0x30f [4889d6]: mov rsi, rdx>
<CsInsn 0x312 [85c0]: test eax, eax>
<CsInsn 0x314 [750a]: jne 0x320>
<CsInsn 0x316 [4883c420]: add rsp, 0x20>
<CsInsn 0x31a [5b]: pop rbx>
<CsInsn 0x31b [5e]: pop rsi>
<CsInsn 0x31c [5f]: pop rdi>
<CsInsn 0x31d [c3]: ret >
<CsInsn 0x31e [6690]: nop >
<CsInsn 0x320 [ba18000000]: mov edx, 0x18>
<CsInsn 0x325 [b901000000]: mov ecx, 1>
<CsInsn 0x32a [e821060000]: call 0x950>
<CsInsn 0x32f [4889c3]: mov rbx, rax>
<CsInsn 0x332 [4885c0]: test rax, rax>
<CsInsn 0x335 [743c]: je 0x373>
<CsInsn 0x337 [8938]: mov dword ptr [rax], edi>
<CsInsn 0x339 [488d0dc0530000]: lea rcx, [rip + 0x53c0]>
<CsInsn 0x340 [48897008]: mov qword ptr [rax + 8], rsi>
<CsInsn 0x344 [ff158a5c0000]: call qword ptr [rip + 0x5c8a]>
<CsInsn 0x34a [488b058f530000]: mov rax, qword ptr [rip + 0x538f]>
<CsInsn 0x351 [488d0da8530000]: lea rcx, [rip + 0x53a8]>
<CsInsn 0x358 [48891d81530000]: mov qword ptr [rip + 0x5381], rbx>
<CsInsn 0x35f [48894310]: mov qword ptr [rbx + 0x10], rax>
<CsInsn 0x363 [ff15b35c0000]: call qword ptr [rip + 0x5cb3]>
<CsInsn 0x369 [31c0]: xor eax, eax>
<CsInsn 0x36b [4883c420]: add rsp, 0x20>
<CsInsn 0x36f [5b]: pop rbx>
<CsInsn 0x370 [5e]: pop rsi>
<CsInsn 0x371 [5f]: pop rdi>
<CsInsn 0x372 [c3]: ret >
<CsInsn 0x373 [83c8ff]: or eax, 0xffffffff>
<CsInsn 0x376 [eb9e]: jmp 0x316>
<CsInsn 0x378 [0f1f840000000000]: nop dword ptr [rax + rax]>
<CsInsn 0x380 [53]: push rbx>
<CsInsn 0x381 [4883ec20]: sub rsp, 0x20>
<CsInsn 0x385 [8b055d530000]: mov eax, dword ptr [rip + 0x535d]>
<CsInsn 0x38b [89cb]: mov ebx, ecx>
<CsInsn 0x38d [85c0]: test eax, eax>
<CsInsn 0x38f [750f]: jne 0x3a0>
<CsInsn 0x391 [31c0]: xor eax, eax>
<CsInsn 0x393 [4883c420]: add rsp, 0x20>
<CsInsn 0x397 [5b]: pop rbx>
<CsInsn 0x398 [c3]: ret >
<CsInsn 0x399 [0f1f8000000000]: nop dword ptr [rax]>
<CsInsn 0x3a0 [488d0d59530000]: lea rcx, [rip + 0x5359]>
<CsInsn 0x3a7 [ff15275c0000]: call qword ptr [rip + 0x5c27]>
<CsInsn 0x3ad [488b0d2c530000]: mov rcx, qword ptr [rip + 0x532c]>
<CsInsn 0x3b4 [4885c9]: test rcx, rcx>
<CsInsn 0x3b7 [742a]: je 0x3e3>
<CsInsn 0x3b9 [31d2]: xor edx, edx>
<CsInsn 0x3bb [eb0e]: jmp 0x3cb>
<CsInsn 0x3bd [0f1f00]: nop dword ptr [rax]>
<CsInsn 0x3c0 [4889ca]: mov rdx, rcx>
<CsInsn 0x3c3 [4885c0]: test rax, rax>
<CsInsn 0x3c6 [741b]: je 0x3e3>
<CsInsn 0x3c8 [4889c1]: mov rcx, rax>
<CsInsn 0x3cb [8b01]: mov eax, dword ptr [rcx]>
<CsInsn 0x3cd [39d8]: cmp eax, ebx>
<CsInsn 0x3cf [488b4110]: mov rax, qword ptr [rcx + 0x10]>
<CsInsn 0x3d3 [75eb]: jne 0x3c0>
<CsInsn 0x3d5 [4885d2]: test rdx, rdx>
<CsInsn 0x3d8 [7426]: je 0x400>
<CsInsn 0x3da [48894210]: mov qword ptr [rdx + 0x10], rax>
<CsInsn 0x3de [e855050000]: call 0x938>
<CsInsn 0x3e3 [488d0d16530000]: lea rcx, [rip + 0x5316]>
<CsInsn 0x3ea [ff152c5c0000]: call qword ptr [rip + 0x5c2c]>
<CsInsn 0x3f0 [31c0]: xor eax, eax>
<CsInsn 0x3f2 [4883c420]: add rsp, 0x20>
<CsInsn 0x3f6 [5b]: pop rbx>
<CsInsn 0x3f7 [c3]: ret >
<CsInsn 0x3f8 [0f1f840000000000]: nop dword ptr [rax + rax]>


b'.CRT\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b"\xba\xd8\x1d\x8fr\xdb\xc0\xd9t$\xf4X1\xc9\xb1V1P\x13\x03P\x13\x83\xe8$\x90z\x8e    <\x82\x85o  \xbc\xe3\x0c\x8a\x8d#j\xde\xbd\x93\xf8\xb21_\xac&\xc2-yHc\x9b_gt\xb0\x9c\xe6\xf6\xcb\x
f0\xc8\xc7\x03\x05\x08\x00y\xe4X\xd9\xf5[MnC`\xe6    <E\xe0\x1b\xf4d\xc1\x8d\x8f>\xc1,\\KH7\x81v\x02\xccq\x0c\x95\x04H\xed:ie\x1cB\xadA\xff1\xc7\xb2\x82A\x1c\xc9X\xc7\x87i*\x7fl\x88
\xff\xe6\xe7\x86\xb4m\xaf\x8aK\xa1\xdb\xb6\xc0D\x0c?\x92b\x88d@\n\x89\xc0'3\xc9\xab\x98\x91\x81A\xcc\xab\xcb\r!\x86\xf3\xcd-\x91\x80\xff\xf2\t\x0f\xb3{\x94\xc8\xc2l'\x06l\xfc\xd
9\xa7\x8c\xd4\x1d\xf3\xdcN\xb7|\xb7\x8e8\xa9-\x85\xaeX\xb1\x99O5\xb3\x99\x9e\x99:\x7f\xf0ql\xd0\xb1!\xcc\x80Y(\xc3\xffzS\x0eh\x10\xbc\xe6\xc0\x8d%\xa3\x9b,\xa9~\xe6o!\x8a\x16!\x
c2\xff\x04V\xb5\xff\xd4\xa7P\xff\xbe\xa3\xf2\xa8V\xae#\x9e\xf8Q\x06\x9d\xff\xae\xd7\x97t\x98M\x97\xe2\xe5\x81\x17\xf3\xb3\xcb\x17\x9bc\xa8D\xbeke\xf9\x13\xfe\x86\xab\xc0\xa9\xee
Q>\x9d\xb0\xaa\x15\x9d\xb7T\xeb\x8a\x1f    <\x13\x8b\x9f\xbcy\x0b\xf0\xd4v$\xff\x14v\xef\xa8    <\xfd~\x1a\xdd\x02\xab\xfaC\x02X'ty\x11\xd8u~;\xbdv~C\xc3K\xa8z\xb1\x8ah9\xca\xb9\xcdhA\x
c1Bj@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@u@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`p@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\xc0\x18@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\xa0@\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\xfcu@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x90@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x00\x00\x00"
<CsInsn 0x200 [bad81d8f72]: mov edx, 0x728f1dd8>
<CsInsn 0x205 [dbc0]: fcmovnb st(0), st(0)>
<CsInsn 0x207 [d97424f4]: fnstenv [rsp - 0xc]>
<CsInsn 0x20b [58]: pop rax>
<CsInsn 0x20c [31c9]: xor ecx, ecx>
<CsInsn 0x20e [b156]: mov cl, 0x56>
<CsInsn 0x210 [315013]: xor dword ptr [rax + 0x13], edx>
<CsInsn 0x213 [035013]: add edx, dword ptr [rax + 0x13]>
<CsInsn 0x216 [83e824]: sub eax, 0x24>
<CsInsn 0x219 [90]: nop >
<CsInsn 0x21a [7a8e]: jp 0x1aa>
<CsInsn 0x21c [3c82]: cmp al, 0x82>
<CsInsn 0x21e [856fbc]: test dword ptr [rdi - 0x44], ebp>
<CsInsn 0x221 [e30c]: jrcxz 0x22f>
<CsInsn 0x223 [8a8d236adebd]: mov cl, byte ptr [rbp - 0x422195dd]>
<CsInsn 0x229 [93]: xchg eax, ebx>
<CsInsn 0x22a [f8]: clc >
<CsInsn 0x22b [b231]: mov dl, 0x31>
<CsInsn 0x22d [5f]: pop rdi>
<CsInsn 0x22e [ac]: lodsb al, byte ptr [rsi]>
<CsInsn 0x22f [26c22d79]: ret 0x792d>
<CsInsn 0x233 [48639b5f6774b0]: movsxd rbx, dword ptr [rbx - 0x4f8b98a1]>
<CsInsn 0x23a [9c]: pushfq >
<CsInsn 0x23b [e6f6]: out 0xf6, al>
<CsInsn 0x23d [cb]: retf >
```

FYI, The two section is first `.data` in op-code which then is disassembled and the bottom part is `.CRT` op-codes and disassembled.

The `.crt` section contains code (I have planted a shellcode there for testing) but `.data` comes with the binary. I haven't stored anything there manually.

Can anyone tell me how to analyze code bytes vs data bytes?

Comment: Are you disassembling a Windows binary?

Comment: @nevilad yes, compiled with mingw gcc

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to distinguish between code and data.
In a "good" windows binary the answer may be found in it's PE header. There is a section list with entries (`IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` structure) for all sections in the binary. Each section entry has a `Characteristics` field that contains section flags. A "code" section should have `IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE` flag set, meaning it's contents is executable. A section without this flag should contain non-executable data.

Section flags can easily be faked, thus they can't give any guarantee. On practice "good" executable sections can also contain data, for example jump tables or strings.

Typically disassemblers start disassembling from entry points - entry point of the executable and exported functions, and
follow the code flow marking as code all bytes reached by the code flow and as data all bytes that are read or written by the code.

Comment: This is true, but still there are ways you could use to differentiate the two, wrote an article for future students: https://neehack.com/article?post=YD9SXLGUIX